# Correctly using indexes on Android Sqlite3 tables?

Tags: java, android, indexing, sqlite

I want to make my queries reasonably efficient, and based on my research so far, in SQL this is done by using indexes.

For example say I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE 
    (_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    NAME_ID INTEGER,
    SOME_VALUE REAL,
    TIMESTAMP TEXT)
```

From what I am reading, indexes are automatically created for primary key fields (so `_ID` is indexed) and `UNIQUE` fields, but sometimes there may be multiple values for a given `NAME_ID`, `SOME_VALUE`, or `TIMESTAMP` so I cannot apply `UNIQUE` to any of them.

One common query might be to select rows in this table with `NAME_ID = x` and `date1 <= TIMESTAMP <= date2`'. Is it correct to say that I should make indexes for both `NAME_ID` and `TIMESTAMP`? Or would I make a composite index:

`CREATE INDEX MYTABLE_INDEX on MYTABLE (NAME_ID, TIMESTAMP);`

or is this the incorrect way to go about it?

If I create these indexes, am I basically done? Have I done all I need to help ensure that future queries on this table will be efficient if I am basing criteria on `NAME_ID` and `TIMESTAMP` like I've shown above?

Comment: Basically, this is it. One other thing you could do is actually run some example queries with and without the index to see that you actually have achieved the desired effect.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to create indexes for all combinations of fields? One for `NAME_ID`, one for `SOME_VALUE`, one for `TIMESTAMP`, one for `NAME_ID` and `SOME_VALUE`, one for `NAME_ID` and `TIMESTAMP`, etc.

Comment: I would say no. Bear in mind that, while indexed speed up queries, they have a negative impact on insert / update / delete speed. I would suggest you use the golden rule - don't optimise unless you have to.

Comment: I ask because it largely depends on how much a user actually uses the app. For example if they're heavily using the app and constantly inserting/queries entries, eventually the database will be reasonably big (thousands of rows).

Comment: The key here is to measure. Simulate a large number of records and see if you are happy with the performance. Then, start optimising the problem ones.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. If you'd like to combine all of this into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarise:

What you have done should be sufficient for your use case.

However, keep in mind the premature optimisation tends to cause more problems in the long run. Start by simulating a large record set and try out all of your queries. If you are not satisfied with the result, then create an index and optimise.

Bear in mind that indexes speed up queries, but slow down inserts / updates / deletes, so adding too many of them on the same table can actually harm performance in some cases.